# Text-to-Object Animation

Tags: animation

[image]I would like to create an animated logo.

The idea is to change two letters into a circular object using animations. Essentially, the two converge into one line where the half circles, made by the letters, align to make a circle cut in half by the line. The entire sequence then spins as the line disappears into the middle, leaving just a circle.

I have attempted to search the communities for video tutorials or someone that may have done something similar or any text-to-object animations. Maybe even combining several ideas if need be, but have come short and am stuck on how to even approach the project.

If anyone has any links or experience in doing such an animation, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Any way to remove the extra space? These are supposed to be half circles so I would expect them to fit together without this happening. Not sure of how to prevent this.

[image]

Comment: I reckon shape keys is the solution but not quite sure how

Comment: You could probably do this animating hooked empties to certain vertices of the text.

Comment: Does this need to be 3D? You accomplish this with SVG using other applications relatively easily if 2D is acceptable.

Comment: Would really like to see a grease pencil version. The new gp is a complete mystery to me.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OZoBJF7JzGmyQ87LxiX53bJx7NeY7U_e

Is this the animation you're talking about? if so, I will explain how it was done.

Comment: @Simon yes exactly!! Please let me know how you went about this.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. For now, just know that you can use this however you like but please inform your client/ employer who created the work (CC-BY), no need to credit me publically. I will gladly create a video tutorial here of this for you tommorow night.

I wish I had seen this when I wasn't about to sleep, will answer tommorow with more Info.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We will use **shape keys**, **vertex groups**, **keyframes**, and **modifiers** to achieve this.

**First, go to edit > Preferences > Animation and make sure the default interpolation of F-Curves is set to Linear**

- Add a Circle. Add>Mesh>Circle
- Immediately press <kbd>F9</kbd> to open the popup menu and set the vertices to 64
- Go into edit mode, select the top most vertex and press <kbd>V</kbd> and right-click to rip it and keep it in place. Do the same to the bottom most vertex. You now have two separate half circles.

[image]

- While still in edit mode with the same object, add a plane. Add/Mesh/Plane
- Press <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd> to scale it to a line along the y axis.
- Press <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd> to set its length to 2.
- Press Right Click > Merge Vertices > By distance so that it is a simple line

[image]

- Add a new vertex group named "Bar Left", click assign.
- Press <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, -0.1 to move it a little bit to the left.
- Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>,  to duplicate, then type <kbd>X</kbd>, 0.20 to position it on the right.
- Add a new vertex group named "Bar Right", click assign, select the "Bar Left" vertex group and click "Remove" so that each bar is assigned to a different vertex group.
- Press <kbd>L</kbd> while overing over the right half-circle to select all the linked vertices.
- Add a new vertex group named "Circle Right"
- Unselect, and do the same for the left half circle. Name the vertex group "Circle Left"
- Move both half circles 0.1 unit on either side along x axis.

[image]

- Tab out of edit mode, add a shape key and then another one. Select the new one and go into edit mode.
- Select the vertices of both bars and press Press <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd> so that they are on the same spot. Move each half circle 0.1 unit closer to the center so that they form a circle again. Tab out of edit mode.
- Go to frame 1 of your animation, and click on the little dot on the right of the value of your keyframe. Make sure the value is "0". The field becomes yellow.

[image]

- Go to frame 10, set the value to 1 and click on the rotated cube on the right of the field. Now when you play your animation, the two bars begin separated and merge at frame 10.
- Add a mask modifier to your object. Select either one of the bar vertex groups, click on the invert icon and press <kbd>i</kbd> while hovering over both the screen icon and the camera icon.
- Go back to frame 9, unchek both these icons and again press <kbd>i</kbd> while hovering over them. The modifier should look like this on frame 10

[image]

- Add a new shape key,and move the right circle 1 unit up and the left circle one unit down on the Y axis
- Tab out of edit mode, set the value to 1 and while still one frame 10, add a keyframe (white little dot on the right)
- Go to frame 40, set the value to 0 and add a keyframe
- While on frame 40, go to the object's transform properties and add a keyframe to the Z rotation set to 0.
- Add a new shape key, select the bar vertices which are not masked by the mask modifier (in my case Bar Left) and scale it to 0 along the y axis
- While on frame 40, add a keyframe on the value of this shape key set to 0
- Go to frame 70, set the rotation to 270° and add a keyframe, set the value of the last shape key to 1 and a a keyframe
- Add a mask modifier and mask the bar from the frame 70 and on. (Same steps as for the first bar) Your modifier should look like this on frame 69 :

[image]

- Add a skin modifier, go into edit mode **after selecting the base shape key**, select all the vertices, type <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and move your mouse to the left to reduce the width of the skin modifier.
  If the skin doesn't appear on parts of the mesh, select one vertex from it and click on "mark root" in the skin modifier.
- Go back to frame 1. Add a new shapekey and mute all the other ones (checkbox on the right of the shape key name)
- Select the vertices of your first half-center and scale it by a value of 2.
  [image]
- Repeat those steps for the other half-circle. Un-mute all the other shapekeys.
- On frame 70, add a keyframe with a value of 0. Go to frame 100 and a keyframe with a value of 1.
- I did not really understand the final parts of your animation but I am sure you can achieve it with the knowledge from this answer. Play with vertex groups, shape keys and masks.
  The final result

[image]

Comment: This *would* be the answer if the text had to be 2D.

Comment: No flash of light?

Comment: I guess not. Using shaders would make that *super* easy.

Comment: This is 3D. I'll update the answer later with the end of the animation now that I understand it

Comment: Could you add some more clarification for the skin modificaiton? Seem to have issues getting the other half circle and lines to appear. Skin modification is only applying to one half and no bars. Thanks

Comment: Oh, yes, I forgot that. you should select at least one vertex from each separate mesh and click on "Mark root" in the skin modifier

Comment: "Add a new shape key, select the circle vertices which are not masked by the mask modifier (in my case Bar Left) and scale it to 0 along the y axis". In this instance, do I select the circle vertices or Bar Left? Confused since they are two separate entities

Comment: Oh right, no it should be the one bar that is still visible at this time in the animation, not the circle parts

Answer (score 6):

This really only applies to the example given, but I found a way to animate the text as shown in the example. I couldn't find any fonts that would work, so I designed my own.
Here's a rendered [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17e5Y_ko2vK7iEYm_UsCrT7GbLyNLwnLB/view?usp=sharing).

This is what to what to do: 
Add a circle make sure the fill type is set to triangle fan:[image]
Go into edit mode and separate half of the faces into a new object by pressing 'P'. We will use the other half as a boolean later:
[image]
Go back to object mode and apply *scale* to the left half by going to options>apply>scale. Then go back to edit mode and extrude it .05 along the Z axis:[image]
Now I selected the other half and did the same. (This can be whatever height as long as it is longer than the first half of the circle:[image]
Then scale that down slightly, move it down the Z axis slightly, rotate it 180 degrees on the Z axis, and transform the origins of both objects to the *center of mass (surface)*. I then aligned both objects along all axes. I also went to edit mode and extruded the face on the boolean half which was on the right side so that it would cut a "C" shape out of the left half:
[image]
Now add a boolean modifier to the left half (the one not cutting the C shape), and make sure that the operation is set to difference. Also make sure that the *solver* is set to *carve*, and that the object carving is the object extruded furthest along the Z axis. Apply the modifier, and delete the carver:
[image] 
Now go into edit mode with the C shape selected, and select the bottom face of the C:[image]
Extrude the face .05 along the Y axis, and select the new face on the right of it:[image]
SHFT-D to duplicate the face, right-click to set it's position to default, and CTRL+H to hook it to an empty:[image]
Now extrude the new face along the X axis until it is about long enough to make the object look like a "D". Then CTRL+H hook that face to a new empty:[image]
Now you are able to animate this line in object mode. Go to object mode, select the object and both empties, and duplicate them. Now rotate them 180 degrees along the Z axis to make a P. You can also adjust the location if you want:[image]
Now you can animate the object (make sure you select the hooks too for each object when you animate). This can be eyeballed, it does not have to be perfect. Set the location for your symbols to start at frame 1 by selecting them, then pressing I>Location. Move to about frame 15, and move the objects to where you want them to be making one circle, then press I>location again.
Before:[image]

After:
[image]

Now between frames 15 and 50 you will want to animate the circle and line spinning while the hooks spin, and converge at the middle getting brighter at the center.
1)Add an empty and parent all objects and hooks to it. This is for rotation so that the rotating for each object doesn't go wacky. BTW when I say all objects I do not meant the camera or any lighting in the scene. I mean just the text animating objects and the hooks. Select the empty, and add a rotation frame by pressing I>rotation for it at frame 1. Do not move it, and set another frame at frame 15. Now go to about frame 50, and rotate it 400 degrees around the Z axis. Then set another rotation frame.
The rotation is set up. Now the hooks. Select all of the objects, and SHFT+S the cursor to the selected. It will now be in the center of the scene. Select empties 1 2 3 and 4, and insert a location keyframe at frame 15. Then skip to frame 50, and SHFT+S snap them to the cursor. Now set another keyframe.
Frame 15:[image]

Frame 50:
[image]
Now select one half at frame 15 and go to edit mode. This is for setting up the shaders. Select *only* the line's faces, and create a new emission material for it. Then assign the material. I have animated the material to be dark at frame 15, and brightness 2 at frame 50. Make sure that the renderer is cycles. Here are my settings for the material:[image]
Now do the same with the same material for the other line in the other object. 
Setting up the material for the other parts of the object is easy. Just select one object, go to edit mode, and press CTRL+I to select the inverse. Now make a new material, and assign that to the selected. Do the same for the other object.
With materials:[image]
The rest is done by basically adding a small cylinder, scaling it until it is about the size of the lines before they disappear in the middle, and adding a boolean so that it has a hole in the middle. Then duplicating it to form rings around the center, and then moving the rings out of the camera view. Then animating the rings so that the bigger ones appear each next frame. Now you are just about done!

Here's the .blend to play around with if you like:[image]
EDIT: updated video to have spin: [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Xi6NtIHgr11jlt_F5POw-oTkDZ23aV1A).

Comment: Can I inquire why you replaced previous answer with this answer?  They appear identical.

Comment: There were just a few things I didn't like about the previous one.

Comment: Appreciate the 3D model! I was considering doing just 2D at first to tackle the basics of the animation and move to 3D later. I see that you move the rings to extend outside the original circle. In order to keep them inside, would you animate them to end just before the edge?

Comment: Yes, it's that easy. You would just make less rings.

Answer (score 1):

I am with @Pythogen on this. You can easily get something better looking if it's not done in 3D

but if it must be in 3D, look up [Metaballs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/metas/index.html) in blender

playing a bit with the shapes and some perspective trickery would give a good result

here is a nice introduction to it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PP14rVhgX9M)

other than that, how I personly would go about it

is just missing with the opacity of objects and some perspective trickery

lazy but works

Comment: I found a way to do it

Comment: please do share it then
That might help others tackle related stuff

Comment: Can you please give me feed back why did my answer get downvoted? Would help for future answers